# How to address Chrome displaying "Aw, Snap!" page while executing tests through ChromeDriver and Selenium through Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

After about an hour of running my selenium browser will display an "Aw, Snap!" page, and I am unable to interact with the browser in any way from the console, and I have to close browser and re-start my script.

Is there an explanation or easy fix for this?

[image: Aw Snap page display]

Comment: Including your code that gets run to produce this error would be a good start to finding an answer.

Comment: I'm using the Selenium Chrome browser to crawl for location information. About ~1000 locations in the "Aw, Snap!" error occurs. I included a delete_all_cookies() after every ~250, thinking the browser might be overloaded, but that did not work.

Comment: ^ This is a problem description, but still not a code sample. It might be better to just break up your URLs in a way that closes & re-initializes a WebDriver instance every 200 or so URLs.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that! Thank you, I'll give that a try

Comment: that page means you've lost your connection to the internet, so there's not much to be done about it except play the dinosaur game.

Comment: Aw snap doesn't mean no internet, it more likely means you're out of RAM

Answer (score 6):

This error screen...

[image: Aw, Snap!]

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** is having problems loading a new **Browsing Context** i.e. the **Chrome Browser** session.

---

### Reason

You are seeing this error about an hour of running **Chrome Browser** based [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) tests and this issue can occur due to reduced size of **`/dev/shm`** i.e. `/dev/shm` running out of space. As an example:

```
mount -o remount,size=64M /dev/shm
```

Ideally it should have been:

```
mount --bind /tmp/ /dev/shm/
```

While running Chromium in Docker environment `64M` size is pretty much reduced state.

---

### Deep dive

As per the discussion in [Issue 522853: Linux: Chrome/Chromium SIGBUS/Aw, Snap! on small /dev/shm](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=522853):

- [`util_posix.cc:GetShmemTempDir`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=522853#c8) on Linux attempts to always use `/dev/shm` for non-executable memory.
- The required size of `/dev/shm` by large depends on the number of renderers, screen resolution, etc.
- At time you may run out of memory due to [large webapps](https://index.hu/) even before running out of space in `/dev/shm`
- At times some Docker containers decides to severely limit the size of their shared memory by default, which may be ok for some workloads, and probably prevents any container from hogging all the memory.

This issue was analyzed and discussed at length in the following discussions:

- [Issue 736452: Add an option to use /tmp instead of /dev/shm](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=736452)
- [Issue 715363: Chrome crashes/fails to load when /dev/shm is too small, and location can't be overridden](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=715363)

---

### Solution

This issue was finally addressed through the [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/fca5d89ce30c4af1f53750de111e774b031f70f5) / [revision](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/fca5d89ce30c4af1f53750de111e774b031f70f5) by fixing `CreateAnonymousSharedMemory()` not to leak FILE when returning fd.

> CreateAnonymousSharedMemory() was modified to return the writable memory handle as a file-descriptor rather than as a FILE. Since POSIX does not provide a standard way to teardown a FILE without also close()ing the underlying file-descriptor, this was achieved by leaking the FILE.
>   We now provide `CreateAndOpenFdForTemporaryFileInDir()`, to avoid the need to wrap the temporary-file descriptor into a FILE at all.

---

### Conclusion

Ensure that:

- `/dev/shm/` is mounted with enough memory.
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

Comment: How to fix this error when run with docker ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I worked around it by restarting my driver every 30 min automatically inside the function.